# Mockito verify method does not detect method invocation

Tags: java, mockito

I'm am trying to verify that a method was called on an object that I have mocked:

```
public class MyClass{
    public String someMethod(int arg){
        otherMethod();
        return "";
    }

    public void otherMethod(){ }
}    

public void testSomething(){
    MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);

    Mockito.when(myClass.someMethod(0)).thenReturn("test");

    assertEquals("test", myClass.someMethod(0));

    Mockito.verify(myClass).otherMethod(); // This would fail
}
```

This isn't my exact code, but it simulates what I am trying to do. The code would fail when trying to verify that `otherMethod()` was invoked. Is this correct? My understanding of the `verify` method is that it should detect any methods called within the stubbed method (`someMethod`)

I hope my question and code is clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a Mockito mock will just return null on all invocations, unless you override with eg. `thenReturn()` etc.

What you're looking for is a `@Spy`, for example:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
MyClass mySpy = Mockito.spy( mc );
...
mySpy.someMethod( 0 );
Mockito.verify( mySpy ).otherMethod();   // This should work, unless you .thenReturn() someMethod!
```

If your problem is that `someMethod()` contains code you don't want executed but rather mocked then inject a mock instead of mocking the method call itself, eg.:

```
OtherClass otherClass; // whose methods all throw exceptions in test environment.

public String someMethod(int arg){
    otherClass.methodWeWantMocked();
    otherMethod();
    return "";
}
```

thus

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
OtherClass oc = Mockito.mock( OtherClass.class );
mc.setOtherClass( oc );
Mockito.when( oc.methodWeWantMocked() ).thenReturn( "dummy" );
```

I hope that makes sense, and helps you a bit.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I want to use `.thenReturn()` on  `someMethod` as well as verify that `otherMethod` was invoked?

Also, doesn't this then render `verify` useless when mocking a class?

Comment: @Ryan: mocking an object means: I don't care what you do in reality. Do what I tell you to do instead. So the implementation of `someMethod()` is replaced by `return "test";` (if invoked with 0 as argument). You typically mock a dependency , i.e. an object used by the class under test, rather than mocking the class under test itself. And then you can verify that the class under test has called the dependency.

Comment: A spy and a mock are two different things, that you should understand first! They behave differently and are used differently in terms of unit testing. If the problem is that there is code inside `someMethod()` that you don't want invoked, then you should mock that code, instead of mocking the `someMethod()` call.

Comment: @JBNizet says it better than me.

Comment: Thanks all, I think I'll need to do some more reading to wrap my head around the concepts